# JAXB Marshal Empty String to Null Globally

Tags: java, jaxb

My question is very similar to [How to prevent marshalling empty tags in JAXB when string is empty but not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110612/how-to-prevent-marshalling-empty-tags-in-jaxb-when-string-is-empty-but-not-null)

The difference is that I am unable to add the annotation to package-info.java as all our JAXB types are generated from schemas with every build.
I also would much prefer not to change JAXB providers if possible.

What I want to achieve is that setting an empty String will not create the element, but I need to set this for all generated JAXB types from many schemas. Is there a way to apply this to all String fields in all generated JAXB classes?

**Update**
I have managed to get the XML adapter generating for all Strings in the schema by making the following changes:

In the project POM, I added this to the maven-jaxb2-plugin:

```
<bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
<bindingIncludes>
    <include>bindings.xjb</include>
</bindingIncludes>
```

And here is my bindings.xjb file:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
                    <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xs:token"
                        parseMethod="com.project.Formatter.parseString"
                        printMethod="com.project.Formatter.printString"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

And the formatting method:

```
public static String printString(final String value)
{
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(value))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return value;
}
```

The problem is that this causes a Null Pointer Exception deep within JAXB. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.SAXOutput.text(SAXOutput.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:490)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:257)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:103)
```

The cause of this problem boils down to this method:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.hasValue(BeanT)
```

The above method will render the element if the value is not null **before** any adapter is run.

Is there any way to override the Accessor used in JAXB so that this will run the adapter before determining whether to render the element? Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Take a look JAXB Binding http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

Comment: Yeah I've had a look at that. Unfortunately the schema documents are quite complex, and there's about 30 different schemas I would need to apply it to. As far as I can tell from that, a single schema must be defined for each binding. Is there a way to apply the binding to all generated JAXB classes?

Comment: You can define globalBinding see the link I posted, I can't remember which attribute exactly but one of them adds nillable to each element. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413281/how-do-i-prevent-jaxbelementstring-from-being-generated-in-a-cxf-web-service-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

What you have done is right, the error you are seeing is due to what I believe is a bug in the [**JAXB reference implementation**](http://jaxb.java.net/). The JAXB RI should be able to handle a null value being returned from an `XmlAdapter`.  This use case works with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), I'll demonstrate below with an example.

**StringAdapter**

Below is an implmentation that does approximately what the one that you will get after you generate your Java model from the XML schema (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html).

```
package forum11894193;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        if("".equals(string)) {
            return null;
        }
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return string;
    }

}
```

**package-info**

Since you are registering a global adapter, it will be referenced from a `package-info` class like the one below (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html).

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
})
package forum11894193;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

**Root**

Below is a sample domain class with a few `String` fields.  Since the `XmlAdapter` was registered at the package level it will apply to all mapped String fields/properties in that package.

```
package forum11894193;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    String a;
    String b;
    String c;

}
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we'll create an instance of `Root` set a couple of the fields to `""` and then marshal it to XML.

```
package forum11894193;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.a = "";
        root.b = "b";
        root.c = "";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output Using JAXB RI**

Using the JAXB RI with this example results in a NPE.  The stack trace is different, but most likely to us using different marshal methods.  I am also using the version of the JAXB RI included in the JDK which is repackaged to `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.Encoded.setEscape(Encoded.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.doText(UTF8XmlOutput.java:294)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:283)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.text(IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:561)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:462)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:314)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
    at forum11894193.Demo.main(Demo.java:17)
```

**Output Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

When MOXy is used as the JAXB provider you get the desired output.  For information on specifying MOXy as your JAXB provider see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <b>b</b>
</root>
```

Comment: I'd seen your post a few times, but didn't realise the 'bug' was the same because the stack trace is different. I agree that it is a bug in the JAXB implementation. I'll give switching to MOXy a try. Would you expect the resulting XML to be identical? If not, it might not be an option.

Comment: @JBarclay - Yes the resulting XML should be identical.  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) is now the default JAXB provider in WebLogic to give you some sense of the compatibility that you can expect.

Comment: I've switched to MOXy, which fixed the problem as you said. Unfortunately, MOXy isn't doing so well with nillable elements. I've updated the question, any ideas?

Comment: @JBarclay - Can you upgrade to EclipseLink 2.4.0?  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: That resolved the issue, thank you for the help. I've removed that part of the question to simplify the view. I'll award the bounty later today when I can. I've also compared the resulting XML and they are functionally identical, as you said.

Comment: Is this bug raised in a JIRA or similar? Does anyone know if it's been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is still a value. That's why the element is created. With that said, what about in your setter methods set the variable to null if the string is empty?

Also, check this thread out
[JAXB: how to make JAXB NOT to unmarshal empty string to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133250/jaxb-how-to-make-jaxb-not-to-unmarshal-empty-string-to-0)

Comment: I understand that the default behaviour is correct, I want to change it. I can't change the setter methods or use the solutions from that link as the JAXB types are constantly regenerated. I need the classes generated by JAXB to include the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code into you Marshall class

```
public static String toXml(Object o, Class clazz, boolean isFormatted, boolean isEmptyNodes) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            if(isEmptyNodes) {
                SessionEventListener sessionEventListener = new NullPolicySessionEventListener();
                properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.SESSION_EVENT_LISTENER, sessionEventListener);
            } else {
                SessionEventListener sessionEventListener = new DiscardEmptyTagSessionEventListener();
                properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.SESSION_EVENT_LISTENER, sessionEventListener);
            }

            // Create a JaxBContext
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {clazz}, properties);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            // Create the UnMarshaller Object using the JaxB Context
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, isFormatted);
            // remove the xml version line from the output
            marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
            // Marshal the employee object to XML and print the output to console
            marshaller.marshal(o, sw);

            return sw.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
}
```