# Force JAXB to Interpret Empty Element as Null not Empty String

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have one particular element in an XSD schema that I'd like JAXB to treat empty element content as null rather than the empty string. The model classes are generated by XJC.

I've seen [this answer for marshalling empty string to null globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894193/jaxb-marshal-empty-string-to-null-globally), and I'm stuck with the RI of JAXB so I'm guessing this won't work for me.

Is there another approach I can take, given that I only need it for one particular element?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is just for one element, below is one way you could get this to work with any JAXB implementation.

### Java Model

**Foo**

Setup your class to use field access by leveraging the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation.  Then initialize the field corresponding to the element as `""`.  The implement the `get`/`set` methods to treat `""` as `null`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private String bar = "";

    public String getBar() {
        if(bar.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return bar;
        }
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        if(null == bar) {
            this.bar = "";
        } else {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

Below is some demo code you can run to see that everything works.

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar/>
</foo>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18611294/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(foo.getBar());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
null
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar></bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Blaise - I should've mentioned that the model classes are generated by XJC. Is there some secret binding sauce I can use to achieve the same effect?